# Дублирующиеся метки «1с-битрикс» и «битрикс»

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Для меток по вопросам битрикса есть несколько меток [битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81), [1с-битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81), [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix), [1c-bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1c-bitrix).

Метка [битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81) имеет синонимы [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix) и [1c-bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1c-bitrix), но метка [1с-битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81) остаётся обособленной.

Предлагаю [битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81) объединить с [1с-битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81) или сделать синонимом для удобства.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создать синоним метки bitrix/битрикс](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-bitrix-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81)

Comment: @AK тот вопрос завершён. А метки до сих пор дублирутся. С «1с-битрикс» так ничего и не сделали

Comment: Какое название более верное, просто битрикс или 1с-битрикс?

Comment: @NickVolynkin более вероятно просто «битрикс» даже если смотреть на текущую статистику вопросов с этой меткой

Comment: А на [сайте](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/) он везде называется 1с-битрикс. В общем синонимизировать - дело одной минуты, надо бы только выбрать правильный вариант.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну все называют сокращённо битрикс + даже продукт от них идёт с названием «битрикс24», хотя построен всё на том же «1С-Битрикс».

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я перед тем как пометить этот вопрос как возможный дубликат - оставил комментарий в раннем вопросе. Кратко, основной тег: битрикс.

Comment: @AK ну ок, будет битрикс

Comment: Кстати, а что за [tag:битрикс24]?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это отдельный продукт. Компания "1с-битрикс" (ранее "битрикс") выпускает несколько продуктов, среди который самый известный это "БУС" (Битрикс Управление Сайтом), он же собственно и есть "битрикс". Битрикс24 - это второй продукт, либо в формате SaaS, либо standalone приложения. Битрикс24 должен быть отдельным тегом, не синонимом.

Comment: Выдержка: «Корпоративный портал - система управления внутренним информационным ресурсом компании для коллективной работы над задачами, проектами и документами, для эффективных внутренних коммуникаций. ».Корпоративный портал это старое название. На самом деле это это сервис для компаний/команда в который включены рабочие чаты, CRM, бизнес процессы, задачи, телефония и много всего. Выпускается как SaaS или как «коробочная версия» — БитриксУправлениеСайтом с надстройками. Построено на основе всё того же битрикса

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Подскажите — отмечать вопрос как копию?